# How can I get the total lines committed today in git?

Tags: git

I found general statistics on git for all the time the repo has existed but I'm interested in doing something like:

```
git today
```

And get things like # of commits, # of lines , etc. broken down by author.

I am mostly interested in # of lines by current user.. I can combine the results of other things on my own

Comment: That is a metric you probably [shouldn't even look at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769716/how-bad-is-sloc-source-lines-of-code-as-a-metric).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see a graphical representation of a git repository's activity, use the `gitstats` utility: http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/

All the following commands assume use of, e.g., bash. By running the following command you can get the first commit that has the same date as today.

```
> first_commit=`git log --pretty=format:"%h" --since "$(date +%Y-%m%-d):00:00"
```

And the following command will process the git repository for statistics:

```
> gitstats -c commit_begin=<COMMIT_ID> . target/gitstats
```

And by combining these we can get a simple command we can set as an alias, if we wish:

```
> first_commit=`git log --pretty=format:"%h" --since "$(date +%Y-%m%-d):00:00" | tail -n1`; gitstats -c commit_begin=$first_commit . target/gitstats
```

Then open `./target/gitstats/index.html` with your preferred browser

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's going to require a bit of scripting to accomplish, but I'd suggest you start by looking at the output of this command:

```
git log --format="format:%ae" --numstat
```

And also note that `git log` can also take a `--after=<date>` argument.

Comment: for example, `git log --since "$(date +%Y-%m-%d):00:00"` will get all commits since midnight (assuming bash or some other shell with `$()` command substitution)

Comment: Nice one @Useless, I'll change my answer to use this script instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete script based on RJo's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
TMPDIR=.tmp.gitstat.$$
mkdir $TMPDIR
trap "rm -fr $TMPDIR" EXIT
gitstats -c commit_begin=$(git log --pretty=format:%h --since $(date +%Y-%m-%d):00:00 | tail -1) . $TMPDIR
lynx $TMPDIR/index.html
```

(obviously replace lynx with your preferred browser, and change the script to either wait for it, or not delete the created directory, if it runs in the background).

Note there's no error checking, and specifically gitstats chokes if there's only one commit (`git shortlog -s COMMIT..HEAD` must be non-empty).