# Gitstats commit_begin does not work

Tags: git, github

I am using gitstats on windows I am trying to get stats for the current month 
however gitstats still returns stats from untill the time the project was created
I am executing this command:

```
git log --since "1 month ago"
```

This gives me a month old commits until date, I copy the first commit_id and then executing

```
python gitstats.py -c commit_begin="commit_id_got_from_above" path_to_git_repo path_to_target
```

My issue looks similar to this but I have tried that too 
[How can I get the total lines committed today in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327868/git-total-lines-committed-today)

Answer (score 3):

To make it work I did modify the line 75 of gitstats, from

```
def getlogrange(defaultrange = 'HEAD', end_only = True):
```

to

```
def getlogrange(defaultrange = 'HEAD', end_only = False):
```